# Eclipse on Mac C/C++

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, gcc, c++11

I'm having a big problem on Eclipse Kepler for Mac!!
Please, help me!!

```
**** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project Working ****
make all 
Building file: ../hello.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF"hello.d" -MT"hello.d" -o "hello.o" "../hello.cpp"
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libmpc.3.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/Saulo/hpc-gcc/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0/4.9.0/cc1plus
  Reason: image not found
g++: internal compiler error: Trace/BPT trap: 5 (program cc1plus)
```

My question is: How can i resolve this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the variable `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the location of libmpc library. To do this, you have to go to Run/Run Configurations and then select Environment tab, then add the variable `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` and finally set its value to the path to the required dylib.

[image: See the screenshot below]